Flutter build fails when i change the kotlin version
[!]
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                      
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details,  
then update the version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of 
/home/liyu/Documents/codergize/megamart-frontend/android/settings.gradle. 
Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19),  
update /home/liyu/Documents/codergize/megamart-frontend/android/build.gradle ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version> 

I have tried to change kotlin version and clean the pub cache.

See this Answer
